# Como generar un dato 2 veces en una llamada a factory laravel 6

Tags: laravel

Holaa, espero que se encuentren bien, tengo una duda, quiero agregar unas rutas de imagenes de manera random con factory, necesito que se agreguen 1 vez para cada carpeta, un ejemplo del resultado que busco seria algo asi:

Imagen 1: img/products/imagen1.jpg
Imagen 2: img/user/imagen2.jpg

Solo puedo hacer que se guarde en 1 carpeta, por ejemplo en products:

```
$factory->define(Image::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $fileName = $this->faker->numberBetween(1, 10).'.jpg';
    return [
        'path' => "img/products/{$fileName}",

    ];

});
```

Como puedo crear tambien una ruta para la carpeta users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es tener otra variable que sea `folder`. Y hacer uso de la función `randomElement` de `faker`.

```
$factory->define(Image::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $fileName = $this->faker->numberBetween(1, 10).'.jpg';
    $folder = $this->faker->randomElement(['products', 'user']);
    return [
        'path' => "img/{$folder}/{$fileName}",
    ];
});
```